# Is it possible to cast an NSDictionary to an object with matching properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting, nsdictionary

Is it possible to cast an `NSDictionary` to an object with matching properties?  For example, say I had an`NSDictionary`:

```
@{@"custId" :  @(101)
  @"custName" : @"Joe"
  @"custAddress" : @"1 Main St"}
```

If I had a `CustModel` class defined with the attributes `custId`, `custName` and `custAddress`, is there a way to just cast them over from the `NSDictionary`, or do I need to individually move each attribute to a `CustModel` object?

Comment: No.  Best is to define an `initWithDictionary` constructor for the target class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just cast the object, but you can use KVC and call `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` on the object (you have to instantiate it) and supply the dictionary and it will do all the work for you.

---

For your additional question, 2 options:

1. Implement `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` to ignore or map
2. Trim the dictionary to remove invalid keys

Comment: one followup question, setValuesForKeysWithDictionary works fine as long as the ALL of the NSDictionary properties match with the CustModel object, but it will fail if the dictionary has other attributes that I may not care about.  Sometimes I may not be able to control this if for example I am getting the dictionary data from a JSON String returned from a web service.  Is there a way to only match it with the attributes that match and ignore the rest?